# Angular get request with multiple queries

Tags: angular, angular8

```
onSubmit() {
this.router.queryParams.subscribe(params => { 
  let opts = { params: new HttpParams({fromObject: {
    "employeeStatus":this.userForm.get('employeeStatus').value,
    "department":this.userForm.get('department').value
  }
})}
//opts = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(opts));
console.log(opts)
  this.http.get<User>(`${this.serverUrl}`, opts).subscribe(
    res => {
      this.user = res
      console.log(res)
    }
  ), 
  console.log(params);
 })
}
```

on submit of form, I want if any control value is null it does not pass in opts. Can anyone help please??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd do it like this if control names match params

```
let opts = { params: this.getHttpParams() };

getHttpParams = () => {
    const httpParams = new HttpParams();
    Object.keys(this.userForm.controls).forEach(key => {
        const value = this.userForm.get(key).value;
        if(value)
           httpParams.append(key, value);
    });

    return httpParams;
}
```

Note if control's value is null or empty string this condition "if(value)..." will evaluate to false

Comment: Its returning correct value when we append but the httpParams that it returns null value in maps. Please can you help me out

Comment: if you can create stackblitz example I'll take a look

Comment: It Working now and thanks for help, HttpParams append method return new body with the appended value. Http Params  is immutable.
 if(value)
          ==> httpParams =  httpParams.append(key, value);
we have to again declare httpParams and it works great

Comment: read this article for detail Creating a URL with HttpParams in Angular for more information https://medium.com/@armno/creating-a-url-with-httpparams-in-angular-42783205f3f4